# Jquery mobile multiple click events when go back into page

Tags: android, click, jquery-mobile

I have just upgraded jquery mobile to beta 2(from beta 1) and I am now receiving multiple click events if i go back into a page after pressing back, each time I go back in it adds another to the click so the alert fires however many times you go into the page

I have also noticed that clicks/taps seem to go through the current page and clicking on pages hidden by view - seems really strange but I am thinking they are probably linked.

It is as if it is creating multiple versions of the same page and when you go back into it loads a new one causing there to be two click events.

Here is a snippet of the code which is being fired

```
$('#click_me').live('vclick', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Hopefully this makes sense and anyone can shed any light on what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

You've probably solved this by now, but you need to use the `pagecreate` event.
@Phill's suggestion of:

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    $('#click_me').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

Unfortunately won't help, but you can solve the issue if you change `pageshow` to `pagecreate`

```
$('div').live('pagecreate',function(){
    $('#click_me').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

If you're not using AJAX to load your pages, make sure also to change `live` to `bind`.

I had this same issue myself and this has solved it completely for me.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

I think the reason is you have the click event tied to the live event, so evrytime you navigate to that page it triggers the click event. try something like this:

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    $('#click_me').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

or just use the click event

```
$('#click_me').click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

When Beta 2 was released they are deprecating vclick

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

**Backtrack: We’ve switched back from vclick to click for links**

> In Beta 1, we decided to use our custom vclick event for handling Ajax
> links to improve responsiveness and to hide the URL bar on the iPhone
> and Android phones. Even though we did quite a bit of testing before
> landing this for Beta 1, we began to hear feedback that this change
> was causing some significant issues out in the wild including:
>
> - Multiple click events causing navigation and form element issue –
>   In certain situations, when tapping an element, tap/click events seem
>   to fire twice on links and is due to edge cases where the target of
>   the touch event and mouse event don’t match due to how the browsers
>   calculate tolerances for these events. This is most pronounced on
>   Android 2.1, but affected most WebKit-based browsers to varying
>   degrees when a tap events occured near the edge of an element.
> - Click handlers in custom scripts didn’t “work” anymore – if a
>   script bound only to click events on the document, the global vclick
>   feature could interfere because the touch events may supercede click
>   events so it events wouldn’t appear to trigger.

Comment: Thanks but i did actually try with click and it did not seem to make any difference :(

Comment: thanks, but didn't seem to work either :(, if it makes any difference the page where the click event is used is a separate html file to index. Not too sure what this could be.